# How to "disperse" the nodes from a graph using Graphsharp and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, graph

everyone. I'm using GraphSharp and WPF to construct a graph which contain many nodes.

The problem is: the nodes usually are disposed one over others, which looks like a "bold" named node (see this image, the red box http://postimg.org/image/tl6gt3cfz/).

I want to disperse the nodes through the window, avoiding the nodes being one over other. 
Is there any way to do that?

Here is the Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:graphsharp="clr-namespace:GraphSharp.Controls;assembly=GraphSharp.Controls"
    xmlns:zoom="clr-namespace:WPFExtensions.Controls;assembly=WPFExtensions"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="350" 
    Width="525"
    x:Name="root">
<Grid>
    <zoom:ZoomControl>
    <graphsharp:GraphLayout x:Name="graphLayout"
                           Graph="{Binding ElementName=root,Path=GraphToVisualize}"
                            LayoutAlgorithmType="FR"
                            OverlapRemovalAlgorithmType="FSA"
                            HighlightAlgorithmType="Simple"/>
    </zoom:ZoomControl>
</Grid>
```

Here is the .cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public IBidirectionalGraph<object, IEdge<object>> _graphToVisualize;

    public IBidirectionalGraph<object, IEdge<object>> GraphToVisualize
    {
        get { return _graphToVisualize; }
    }

    public MainWindow(int[,] matrix, string[] names)
    {
        CreateGraphToVisualize(matrix, names);

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void CreateGraphToVisualize(int[,] matrix, string[] names)
    {
        var g = new BidirectionalGraph<object, IEdge<object>>();

        //add the vertices do the graph
        string[] vertices = new string[matrix.GetLength(0)];

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            vertices[i] = names[i];
            g.AddVertex(vertices[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (i == j) break;

                if(matrix[i,j]==1) g.AddEdge(new Edge<object>(vertices[i], vertices[j]));
            }
        }

        _graphToVisualize = g;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The graph is using a force-directed algorithm (You specify LayoutAlgorithmType="FR")
The layout algorithm take a parameter of type FRLayoutParametersBase, which has an attractionMultiplier and repulsiveMultiplier. Tweaking those numbers will cause your nodes to space differently.
I'm not familiar with GraphSharp and have never used it before, so am not sure what is the most appropriate way to go about doing this.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought something like this. I've tried changing the LayoutAlgorithmType to other types, and it worked.
In this case, I used LayoutAlgothimType="ISOM".

If someone is getting trouble with this. Consider trying other Layout Algorithm Types.


Thanks for the answer, Glen!